# What would be a definition of Affine Invariance with respect to B-Splines?

Tags: curves, affine-geometry

I might be missing the obvious here. Still, I understand an affine transformation is a transformation that preserves collinearity and ratio of lengths, and I'm struggling to understand what it means for B-Splines to be affine invariant though. I know that when an affine transformation is applied to a B-Spline, we only need to apply the transformation to the control points to find the new curve. Is this all there is to say?

Thank you for any help

Comment: Basically, yes. However, this question is not research level math and should have been asked on Math.SE.

Comment: An affine transformation need not preserve ratios of lengths; the generic affine transformation in the plane or in space does not. It preserves ratios of lengths of sets of colinear points.